# How to get these both results in one Row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an query which collects the results of my table.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT id, number FROM from list
union select id, number from list
```

both fields are integer and the id is doubled but the number is unique.

this is the result

```
id     number
19564  234287
19564  234288
```

What do I have to do to that it looks like this:

```
id     number
19564  234287;234288
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic.  Your `union` appears to have the same columns and table on both the left and right side.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-aggregate.html)?

```
select id, string_agg(distinct number, ';')
from list
group by id;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. 
For me, this doesn´t work. I´ve converted the integer (number) to a string twith , but i always get two results.

Comment: @ChristophD . . . If you get two rows, then the `id`s are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a crosstab query

```
/* TO CREATE CROSSTAB EXTENSION*/
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

/* CROSSTAB QUERY */
SELECT * FROM crosstab (  
  'SELECT
    id,
    number   
  FROM list 
  ORDER BY id ASC, number ASC;')
 AS ct(
   id INT,
   firstnumber NUMERIC,
   secondnumber NUMERIC )
 ;
```

**RESULT:**

```
|___id___|_firstnumber_|_secondnumber_|
| 19564  |   234287    |    234288    |
```

If that works to you and you want both amounts in one single column, you could try concatenating them.

Hope it helps.